# Hypothetical selective breeding scenario question two?

Tags: biology, evolution, dinosaurs

Could one using selective breeding and artificial induced selective pressures breed a tree climbing Anole lizard to become something that resembles a gliding pterosaur from the Mid Triassic or early Jurassic period.

Comment: How long have you got?  A few thousand years should suffice.

Comment: *artificial induced selective pressures* This won't make any practical difference to the genetic  makeup of a race for a huge timescale - this is just raw evolution.  Very slow.

Comment: @StephenG: That's why after a few thousand years of selective breeding chihuahuas and great danes are still almost indistinguishable and very similar to gray wolves.

Comment: the answer could depend on lots of restrictions, for one, when asking "Could one.." do you mean a single person in their life span? Another example would be, could you artificially induce mutations so you could create new traits in your population on which to apply your selective pressures on or selectively breed from?

Answer (score 1):

I would say - **no**.

Theoreticaly, as current science knowledge implies, having unlimited time and resources you can turn any species into any other speices. But practicaly you would require to much of both for such a change.

You see, problem is that modern lizard are not like ancient lizards - they evolved a lot of new features. While pterosaurs (they were more like birds in behaviour and were not just gliders) evolved a lot of completely different features. Сomparison of these is a good subject for a scientific paper. Many of those features are exclusive.

So the process is very complex, it is like breeding pigs into whales (both are even-toed ungulates). It is absolutely unrealistic for a simple selective breeding.